# Subversion merge trunk into existing tag

Tags: svn, merge, tags, branch

I'm currently having the following setup in my SVN-repository:

```
-Root
--ProjectA
----trunk
----tags
----branches
--ProjectB
----trunk
----tags
----branches
--ProjectPool
----projectA
----projectB
```

Where ProjectPool contains specific tags of ProjectA and ProjectB.

Now the tags in ProjectPool change from time to time. This means a specific trunk-version of ProjectA is commited and I want to create a copy from this revision into Root/ProjectPool/projectA. The new tag should replace the old tag, but there should be a history available.

Its like having a branch on my computer which I never change and from time to time merging the trunk into it. But it should be done on the repository completely. (without having to checkin/checkout etc)

This would allow me to look into Root/ProjectPool/projectA's history and see the changes of it. Kind of a high-level revision-history.

**UPDATE:**
I'm sorry I forgot to ask a clear question -.-
After viewing the answers which have been arrived until now, I would say that the copies of projects in ProjectPool are branches of the original projects. I then could merge them from trunk anytime I need a new version in ProjectPool.
The question now is, if there is a way to do the merging "online", without having to create a working copy first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> >>Now the tags in ProjectPool change from time to time.

`Tags` are milestones, they should not be changing. You should create a new tag on each release.

> >>This means a specific trunk-version of ProjectA is commited and I want to create a copy from this revision into Root/ProjectPool/projectA. The new tag should replace the old tag, but there should be a history available.

What you need here is a **`branch`** of `ProjectA` under `ProjectPool` which you can repetitively merge with **`trunk`** of `ProjectA`. With something like this

```
  svn merge sourceURL1[@N] sourceURL2[@M] [WCPATH]
```

refer: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html

> >>This would allow me to look into Root/ProjectPool/projectA's history and see the changes of it. Kind of a high-level revision-history.

Looks like you have gone ahead with your directory structure. I would suggest you to follow this structure, if possible.

```
-Root
    +--ProjectPool
        +--ProjectA
            +----trunk
            +----tags 
            +----branches
        +--ProjectB
            +----trunk
            +----tags
            +----branches
```

You can *release* ProjectA and ProjectB in their `tag`s. Newer development will continue in `trunk`. For any side development, or spot release, create a `branch` in branches directory. When branch is done, merge it back to trunk. This way your `trunk` will always reflect all the revisions and changes. And, this is more handy (and conventional).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You wrote, that I need a branch under `ProjectPool` which I should repetitively merge with trunk. That is exactly what I meant when writing `Its like having a branch on my computer which I never change and from time to time merging the trunk into it.`. I'm now looking for a way to to the merging "online" without having to get a working copy.

Comment: @MOnsDaR what you want is `merge` and `commit` combo command. I seriously doubt if that's possible. Merging complete process is `merge`, `resolve` and `commit` in that sequence. I understand that in your case `resolve` is not there, but `SVN` cannot assume that possibility. So, I guess you will have to commit explicitly. The command mentioned in the URL will merge in current directory. So, if you are confident you may write a shell script. That merges and commits. But still, there will be downloads.

Comment: I think that sums up what I'm trying to do and how to achieve it, so I marked it as accepted answer. Thanks Nishant and all other answerers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really make any question so I'm not sure whether you're aware of the `merge` subcommand but that's the one you need:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html

Pay special attention to the `--accept` parameter; you need it in order to get automated conflict resolution:

```
C:\>svn help merge
[...]
  --accept ARG             : specify automatic conflict resolution action
                            ('postpone', 'base', 'mine-conflict',
                             'theirs-conflict', 'mine-full', 'theirs-full',
                             'edit', 'launch')
```

I also recommend reading the [Branching and merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.using.html) chapter in the Subversion book.