# Difference between svn tag and svn revision

Tags: svn

Suppose I am trying to do a code merge from DEV branch to Trunk with a specific revision (latest). Is it possible that the change set will be different in case I do the merge via tags (made on DEV branch on same revision number) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subversion merge trunk into existing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825786/subversion-merge-trunk-into-existing-tag).